# Array with Cells() as the parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an array holding Cells() locations as parameters.

When I run the code below it doesn't grab those parameter as I'd hope. Is there something I'm doing wrong or will what I'm trying to do not work this way? The other arrays you see are working accordingly so please ignore those.

```
Dim varDept As Variant
Dim varSheet As Variant
Dim varCell As Variant 
Set DRag = Range("D2:D200")


varCell = Array(Cells(9, 1), Cells(15, 1), Cells(21, 1))

For Each Custom In DRag
    If PDrag = Empty And Custom = varDept(0) And Custom.Offset(0, -1) = "551098218" Then
        PDrag = Custom.Address(0, 0) & "," & Custom.Offset(0, -3).Address(0, 0)
    ElseIf Custom = varDept(0) And Custom.Offset(0, -1) = "551098218" Then
        PDrag = PDrag & "," & Custom.Address(0, 0) & "," & Custom.Offset(0, -3).Address(0, 0)
    End If
Next Custom

If PDrag = Empty Then Exit Sub

PDrag = Replace(PDrag, "D", "E")
Range(PDrag).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets(varSheet(0)).Activate
varCell(0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Normally there's no need to select.

Comment: What you have there will select cell(9, 1), what do you want it to do?

Comment: So this is just a portion of what I have, but the aim is to grab a cell and paste some already copied information into it.

Comment: ```varCell(0).value = variable```

Comment: So you are saying I need to store the value of the current array location to its own variable and then I can use .select ? Sorry I am very new to any type of coding at all and I have been learning as I go. It just errors out on that line of code for varCell(0).Select

Comment: [Don't use Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Is the error Runtime 1004? That means you are trying to select a cell that is on a different sheet from the currently active sheet.

Comment: Run-time error '424': Object required. I'll edit my post and show more of the code if needed.

Comment: Did you by chance delete cells before this? More code would be helpful.

Comment: No the cells are not being deleted. Sorry I fixed the edit.

Comment: Empty is just checking to see if the PDrag is empty when doing the For.. Each loop. its just the initial check.

Comment: Personally I would declare `PDrag` as a string and test `PDrag = ""`

Comment: Actually looking at what you want `PDrag` to do , I would use `Union` instead and make `PDrag` a range object.